# Smallest number $n$ for which $p\mid n!+1$ and $n\nmid p-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My question is that:  What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $n!+1$ is divisible by $p$ and $p-1$ is not divisible by $n$ and give some examples for $n$

This is my question, I try to compute by hands and up to $n=1,2,3,4,5$, there is no such prime $p$. I can prove that there are infinitely such $n$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you illuminate me to your proof of there being infinitely many?

Comment: $8!+1$ is divisible by the prime $61$, and $60$ is not divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$8!+1$ is divisible by $61$ and $661$, neither of which is congruent to $1$ mod $8$.

See [OEIS sequence A064164](https://oeis.org/A064164) and the paper of G. E. Hardy and M. V. Subbarao mentioned there.